# Ajax tab container showing incorrect text

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, ajax, tabs

I have a `ajaxToolKit:TabContainer` on my website. I have **three** tabs that every `Product` populates in some form or another (Description, Additional Information, Reviews). I also have **three** other tabs that are dynamically created, and loaded into the tab container if the products ***meet certain criteria***. I am running into a problem when I load in those three dynamic tabs though.

When I load the tabs, the text from the `Description` tab shows in all the other tabs until I click on the `Description` tab, it then disappears from all the other tabs.

It happens in all the browsers that I really care about (Chrome, IE, FF). The `html` markup, when you view the source, has the text within the correct `div` and `tab panel` but it is displaying incorrectly for some reason.

Here is how I load the controls in the Code behind and add them the container:

```
            TabPanel overviewTab = new TabPanel();

            ProductOverviewInfo control = (ProductOverviewInfo)Page.LoadControl("~/Controls/ProductOverviewInfo.ascx");
            control.overview_populate();

            overviewTab.Controls.Add(control);
            overviewTab.HeaderText = "OVERVIEW";
            ProductTabs.Controls.AddAt(firstVisibleTab, overviewTab);
```

`firstVisibleTab` is just an int value deciding where I want to insert the tab.

Now, I found a fix for this but it is not what I want and not what my project sponsor wants either. If I just use `ProductTabs.Control.Add(tab)` then I don't have the problem. BUT if the product meets the criteria to have an overview tab (the code above) I want that tab to be active.

Now, you may ask, why don't you just use the `.Add(tab)` and then have the `ActiveTabIndex` be where you inserted the new tab. Well, I tried that and for some reason when I would do the check (or just add it in directly in the code above) the whole `TabContainer` would not display, at all.

So in about half of the products I am working with I have the problem of this text showing in the wrong tab, the other half doesn't have the problem because there is no overview tab (or the other 2 dynamically loaded tabs) present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used a jquery hack to hide the tabs panel. The native javascript for the panel makes it show again. not the cleanest but it worked for what I wanted to do.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(".ajax__tab_panel").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

make dynamically created tab in the first position is really required? . because it just inheriting the content from the previouly existing tab